# FileZilla issue connecting with godaddy ftp server

Tags: godaddy, ftp

I have a hosting service with Godaddy and want to connect to FTP to transfer files. I am using filezilla client to transfer stuff. However I am having problem that sometimes it connects just fine, sometimes it starts giving these messages:

```
Status: Connecting to 166.62.10.53:21...

Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...

Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------

Response:   220-You are user number 5 of 500 allowed.

Response:   220-Local time is now 02:44. Server port: 21.

Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login

Response:   220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.

Command:    AUTH TLS

Response:   502 AUTH TLS OK.

Command:    AUTH SSL

Error:  Could not connect to server

Status: Waiting to retry...
```

I noticed that sometimes, when it connects to the server it doesn't do above calls. It just gets to the server and I can transfer files. I am able to understand why it does differently sometimes and different sometimes.

I have all connection strings saved in site manager, so I am not changing anything on my side. It just my lucky day when it connects and I can work with it. Otherwise I have to wait for another day :(
I have tried Godaddy help but it's useless and worst service ever. I searched online too, but couldn't find any useful tips. Can anyone please help in figuring out what the problem is and how to resolve it?

Comment: So I am able to coneect today using same settings in FileZilla, made no changes since yesterday. these are the lines from FileZilla tool:

Status: Connecting to 166.62.10.53:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Status: Directory listing of "/" successful

Not sure what makes it unstable. If someone knows, please help. 

Thanks
Vikas

Comment: Have you tried an alternate FTP client?  Does Godaddy offer alternate upload methods such as SCP?